# Connection between chassis GND to circuit GND

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, grounding, leakage-current

I have two requirements to use a chassis

1. Reduce circuit board leakage
2. Dissipate heat

In my application I'm using the connection as shown below.
[image]

Here I have fixed the chassis over the SMPS through thermal pad as SMPS produce some heat when I use continuous current for charging. SMPS is a PCB mount unit which is located on the PCB. Also connected the circuit GND - Earth wire through the chassis to pass the leakage produced in circuitry as class 2 SMPS doesn't have a earth contact in built. My problem solves and the leakage current passes to the earth through the chassis. This is the condition where the building earth is good.

But when there will be a bad/noisy earth what will be the effect on my circuit GND ? If it interrupts the functionality then what is the solution. Can anyone suggest

Comment: What does this mean --> Reduce circuit board leakage. Your circuit needs to be shown schematically if you want to know how it might be vulnerable.

Comment: This is the simplified blocks of all connections. In previous versions of this board, I didn't use a metal/chassis. So I get some leakage current in the board(GND). After I did this connection leakage is reduced from the circuit GND

Comment: @Andyaka, you can assume by removing chassis/metal plate, screw points and earth wire. That was my previous supply connection

Comment: Which power supply it is, does it have a datasheet you can link to?

Comment: Hi, @Justme , Its IRM 20 12 from Meanwell. https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/IRM-20/IRM-20-spec.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you sketched is a typical scheme of AC L-N-PE **in** and isolated VDC+/- **out**.

SMPS always leak a little bit of mains to the isolated side. This leakage either takes the form of a large 50 Hz common mode voltage on the isolated side which is often tolerable. However, in your design with the earthed metal chassis it looks more probable that you directly return that leakage into PE, which is also a standard tactic.

This second approach is achieved by attaching PE to either VDC+ or VDC-. You attached it to VDC-, which means that your VDC- will be roughly at PE potential and VDC+ will be 12 V above. This method strongly *reduces* the common-mode voltage of the DC side from about ~100VAC to ~6 VDC.

### What about noise in PE?

This noise becomes common-mode noise in your circuit. But! You would have pretty much the same noise if you wouldn't earth the DC side, because for EMC reasons, the PE is anyway capacitively connected inside the SMPS.

As a result, earthing the DC side is almost always much quieter than leaving it floating at the mains frequency.

The proper way to do it, is to connect your VDC- rail to PE at only **a single point**. This prevents that any circuit return currents pass through your chassis or vice versa. A convenient point for this is right at the SMPS, as you have done. Two connection points both at the SMPS are also ok. The emphasis on "single point" is really about the circuit return currents. I.e. don't put a second connection point on the far side of your digital circuit.

Comment: thanks for the input. I get this is convenient for the implementation. Have to see the performance in long term use. @tobalt